# Stop_create unless .first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Afternoon

I have the following code stopping creation of more snippets if not approved but since I'm creating the first snippet there is nothing to reference so some help on how I would write this would be very useful.

```
validate :stop_create, :on => :create

    def stop_create
        errors.add(:base, "could not add due to last snippet not approved") if self.last.approved == false
end
```

Comment: whats the actual problem, question is not very clear to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether last snippet actually exists before attempting to get its status.

```
 def stop_create
   errors.add(:base, "could not add due to last snippet not approved") if Snippet.last && Snippet.last.approved == false
 end
```

OR

```
def stop_create
   errors.add(:base, "could not add due to last snippet not approved") if Snippet.last.try(:approved) == false
 end
```

Comment: This worked but I had to change self.last.try to Snippet.last.try? but I don't understand why?

Comment: .last method should be called on a class, not on an instance object and self in a validate callback is object that is being validated (an instance)